# Any idea on how to decrease Google AMP validation time in Google directory

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I've recently made an AMP site with a Wordpress theme without using any extension. Then in the Google Search console there were a couple of errors. I fixed all of them and now Search Console says my site is AMP compatible when I test my site via live URL. But in Google directory my status didn't update for a while -3 days-.

So my question is how much does it take Google to list my site as AMP compatible? And I would be happy if I can find out how to decrease this validation time.

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

[You're able to ask Google to re-crawl](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en) your site in the [Google Webmasters tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/#?modal_active=none), but it can take some time. It can take anywhere from a few days to a few weeks. Once you've requested a re-crawl there's no way to speed the process up.